# Карта leaflet отображается не корректно

Tags: angular, ionic

Когда страница загружается карта открывается не полностью.
Вот скрин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А когда меняю размер экрана, то карта грузится полностью

map.component.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
const map = L.map('map', {
  minZoom: 1,
}).setView([43.2566700, 76.9286100], 5);

const url =
  'https://www.gtrack.co.id/TileMapService/TileMap.ashx?cachetype=1&tilex={x}&tiley={y}&level={z}';
L.tileLayer(url, {
  attribution: 'Leaflet',
  zoomOffset: 1,
  // tms: true,
}).addTo(map);
```

}

map.component.html

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: leaflet.css не забыли добавить?

Comment: его тоже добавил

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблемой, Вы нашли ответ?